# Incorrect strange nonsense making iOS Crashlytics reports due to insufficient free ram?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crashlytics

I have a concerning amount of crashes for my iOS app. When I look at the stacktrace I can follow the flow of the stacktrace up until the 3d line 'fetchDeezerTracks(forAlbum)'. When inspecting my code it should be impossible for this line to be even called. the ApplePlayerManager.play method calls the ApplePlayerManager.fetchTrackIds method which calls a NetworkManager's 'fetchAppleMusicTracks' and this method has a networkRequestResponseHandler to deal with the fetched data, but NEVER ever should/could the 'fetchDeezerTracks' method be called.

My question is the following: Is it possible for Crashlytics to give incorrect reports maybe when the device's free RAM is insufficient? Maybe due to memory leaks or something... I just can't make sense out of the crash report so it would help me a lot to know if something else is at play. Some of the free RAM values of the multiple reports (of the same crash) are the following:

233MB (iPad Air 2), 8MB (iPAad 5th gen), 198MB (iPad Mini 2), 332MB (iPad Mini), 71MB (iPad Air 2), 174MB (iPad 5th gen), 223MB (iPad Air 2), 130MB (iPhone6+), 58MB (iPhoneXR), 381MB (iPhoneXSMax), etc.

Are these normal values?

If these are normal values and crashlytics reports are never "corrupted" then  I need to make sense of the stacktrace. I'll add my networking code for reference.

Any help very much appreciated! This is driving me mad and crashes keep on piling up.

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  MyApp                          0x10045da40 closure #2 in ApplePlayerManager.play(album:withTrack:) + 4302494272 (<compiler-generated>:4302494272)
1  MyApp                          0x10045d884 closure #1 in closure #1 in ApplePlayerManager.fetchTrackIds(forAlbum:completionHandler:) + 4302493828 (<compiler-generated>:4302493828)
2  MyApp                          0x1004da218 specialized NetworkManager.networkRequestResponseHandler(withResponse:completionHandler:retryHandler:) + 4303004184 (<compiler-generated>:4303004184)
3  MyApp                          0x1004d9404 closure #1 in NetworkManager.fetchDeezerTracks(forAlbum:withAccessToken:withCompletionHandler:) + 4303000580
4  MyApp                          0x1004d8294 closure #1 in NetworkManager.fetchAppleMusicTracks(forAlbumID:withAccessToken:withCompletionHandler:) + 4302996116
5  Alamofire                      0x100a73e64 $s9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0bkF0VyypG_Tg5Tm + 132
6  Alamofire                      0x100a79d08 $s9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0bkF0VyypG_Tg5TATm + 36
7  Alamofire                      0x100a5b3b0 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 28
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18f0eb9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18f0ec524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f0a156c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 684
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f0a1bf8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 124
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18f13db38 _pthread_wqthread + 212
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18f140740 start_wqthread + 8
```

How I fetch my trackIds (NetworkManager)

```
    func fetchAppleMusicTracks(forAlbumID albumID:String,
                           withAccessToken accessToken:String,
                           withCompletionHandler completionHandler:@escaping(JSON?)->Void) {

    let url = kAppleMusicAlbumURL + albumID
    guard let encodedURL = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else { return completionHandler(nil) }
    let headers = [kAppleMusicAuthoritationKey : kAppleMusicBearerKey + accessToken]
    Alamofire.request(encodedURL,
                      method: .get,
                      parameters: nil,
                      encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                      headers: headers).responseJSON(queue: backgroundQueue) {
        [weak self]
        response in
        guard let self = self else { completionHandler(nil); return }

        self.networkRequestResponseHandler(withResponse:response,
                                           completionHandler:completionHandler) {
            self.fetchAppleMusicTracks(forAlbumID: albumID,
                                       withAccessToken: accessToken,
                                       withCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
        }
    }
}
```

my network request handler (NetworkManager):

```
func networkRequestResponseHandler(withResponse response:DataResponse<Any>,
                                   completionHandler: @escaping(JSON?)->Void,
                                   retryHandler: @escaping()->Void) {
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        completionHandler(JSON(value))
    case .failure(let error):
        if self.noConnectionValidator(forError: error, withRetryHandler:retryHandler) { return completionHandler(nil) }
        if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
            let message = BackendManager.sharedInstance.APIErrorMessageHandler(status: status)
            AlertsManager.sharedInstance.displayAlertWithOKButton(forTitle: kGenericErrorTitle,
                                                                  message: message,
                                                                  buttonTitle: "Ok")
        } else {
            AlertsManager.sharedInstance.displayNetworkErrorMessage(withError: error)
        }
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
```

method to fetch tracks (ApplePlayerManager):

```
private func fetchTrackIds(forAlbum album:String, completionHandler:@escaping([String]?)->Void) {
    retrieveAccessToken {
        accessToken in

        guard let accessToken = accessToken else { completionHandler(nil); return }
        NetworkManager.sharedInstance.fetchAppleMusicTracks(forAlbumID: album, withAccessToken: accessToken) {
            JSON in

            guard let JSON = JSON else {
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
            }
            if let tracks = JSON[kAppleMusicDataKey].array?[0][kAppleMusicRelationshipsKey][kAppleMusicTracksKey][kAppleMusicDataKey].array {
                let trackIds = tracks.map{ $0[kAppleMusicTrackIdentifierKey].string }.compactMap{ $0 }
                completionHandler(trackIds)
            } else {
                //AlertsManager.sharedInstance.displayAppleMusicCouldNotFetchTracks()
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

entry-point -> method to play an Apple track (ApplePlayerManager):

```
override public func play(album:String, withTrack track:Int) {
    super.play(album: album, withTrack: track)
    guard let streamingManager = streamingManager else { return setup { self.play(album: album, withTrack: track) } }
    indexOfLastPlayingItem = track
    fetchTrackIds(forAlbum: album) {
        [weak self]
        trackIds in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        guard let trackIds = trackIds else {
            return //AlertsManager.sharedInstance.displayAppleMusicTracksFetchFailed()
        }
        self.loadedAlbumTrackIDs = trackIds
        if let remainingTracks = self.calculateRemainingTrackList(fromCurrentTrack: track) {
            ThreadManager.sharedInstance.executeOnMainThread {
                self.play(forStreamingManager: streamingManager, remainingTracks: remainingTracks)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT - MORE INFO:

Since my app is using multiple services, I made an abstract PlayerManager singleton class with concrete singleton subclasses for every service. so the PlayerManager.play(track: trackId) will call the correct concrete class method on ApplePlayerManager if beforehand the PlayerManager.service is set to .Apple

I know it looks like somewhere in code the singleton has incorrectly changed service, but again it would not make any sense + I can not reproduce it nor getting a breakpoint hit.

EDIT PART II - ALL THREADS STACKTRACES:

I am getting the suspicion that this might be thread related? Here are all the threads:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000104cd5a40
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  MyApp                          0x104cd5a40 closure #2 in ApplePlayerManager.play(album:withTrack:) + 4376304192 (<compiler-generated>:4376304192)
1  MyApp                          0x104cd5884 closure #1 in closure #1 in ApplePlayerManager.fetchTrackIds(forAlbum:completionHandler:) + 4376303748 (<compiler-generated>:4376303748)
2  MyApp                          0x104d52218 specialized NetworkManager.networkRequestResponseHandler(withResponse:completionHandler:retryHandler:) + 4376814104 (<compiler-generated>:4376814104)
3  MyApp                          0x104d51404 closure #1 in NetworkManager.fetchDeezerTracks(forAlbum:withAccessToken:withCompletionHandler:) + 4376810500
4  MyApp                          0x104d50294 closure #1 in NetworkManager.fetchAppleMusicTracks(forAlbumID:withAccessToken:withCompletionHandler:) + 4376806036
5  Alamofire                      0x105313e64 $s9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0bkF0VyypG_Tg5Tm + 132
6  Alamofire                      0x105319d08 $s9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0bkF0VyypG_Tg5TATm + 36
7  Alamofire                      0x1052fb3b0 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 28
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9a9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9b524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e8165c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 640
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e81cd0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eecb38 _pthread_wqthread + 212
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef740 start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.main-thread

com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fa9198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fa860c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b31533b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1b314e3e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1b314dc34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5  GraphicsServices               0x1bd29738c GSEventRunModal + 160
6  UIKitCore                      0x1b728022c UIApplicationMain + 1932
7  MyApp                          0x104cd1060 main + 12 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
8  libdyld.dylib                  0x1b2fd5800 start + 4
com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fa9198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fa860c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b31533b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1b314e3e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1b314dc34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5  Foundation                     0x1b3490bcc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6  Foundation                     0x1b3490aac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7  UIKitCore                      0x1b7322160 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152
8  Foundation                     0x1b35bf9d0 __NSThread__start__ + 848
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eebd98 _pthread_start + 156
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef74c thread_start + 8

com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer

com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  MyApp                          0x104d7b448 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4376982600
1  MyApp                          0x104d7b830 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4376983600
2  MyApp                          0x104d6b09c CLSHandler + 4376916124
3  MyApp                          0x104d66ac4 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4376898244
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eebd98 _pthread_start + 156
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef74c thread_start + 8
com.apple.root.background-qos
com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1b2ec6154 calloc + 98
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1b31e23c4 __CFAllocateObject + 20
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b3205b38 __NSDictionaryM_new + 128
3  Foundation                     0x1b3586e68 _encodeObject + 964
4  Foundation                     0x1b34a2334 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 360
5  Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
6  MyApp                          0x104d372f8 Album.encode(with:) + 4376703736 (<compiler-generated>:4376703736)
7  MyApp                          0x104d37354 @objc Album.encode(with:) + 4376703828 (<compiler-generated>:4376703828)
8  Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
9  Foundation                     0x1b34a2334 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 360
10 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
11 MyApp                          0x104cec884 Series.encode(with:) + 4376397956 (<compiler-generated>:4376397956)
12 MyApp                          0x104cec93c @objc Series.encode(with:) + 4376398140 (<compiler-generated>:4376398140)
13 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
14 Foundation                     0x1b34a2334 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 360
15 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
16 MyApp                          0x104cfcaf0 User.encode(with:) + 4376464112 (<compiler-generated>:4376464112)
17 MyApp                          0x104cfcc64 @objc User.encode(with:) + 4376464484 (<compiler-generated>:4376464484)
18 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
19 Foundation                     0x1b34a2334 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 360
20 Foundation                     0x1b34ccea0 -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) encodeWithCoder:] + 876
21 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
22 Foundation                     0x1b34ed5c8 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 124
23 SwiftyUserDefaults             0x105c9b8c4 $sSo14NSUserDefaultsC010SwiftyUserB0E7archiveyyAC0B3KeyCyxSgG_AGtlF + 292
24 MyApp                          0x104d3a7f8 closure #1 in UserManager._cachedSavedUsers.didset + 4376717304 (<compiler-generated>:4376717304)
25 MyApp                          0x104d05e10 partial apply for closure #1 in ThreadManager.executeOnMainThread(afterSeconds:withBlock:) + 4376501776 (<compiler-generated>:4376501776)
26 MyApp                          0x104d5fc98 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4376870040 (<compiler-generated>:4376870040)
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9a9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9b524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
29 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e8165c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 640
30 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e81cd0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112
31 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eecb38 _pthread_wqthread + 212
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef740 start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fa9198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fa860c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b31533b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1b314e3e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1b314dc34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5  CFNetwork                      0x1b6412c44 (Missing)
6  Foundation                     0x1b35bf9d0 __NSThread__start__ + 848
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eebd98 _pthread_start + 156
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef74c thread_start + 8

com.apple.root.background-qos

com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x1b2edd948 _platform_memmove + 88
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1b2ebc628 szone_realloc + 544
2  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1b2ec5a9c malloc_zone_realloc + 168
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1b2ec625c realloc + 196
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1b30f3948 __CFSafelyReallocate + 28
5  Foundation                     0x1b3555ea0 _NSMutableDataGrowBytes + 344
6  Foundation                     0x1b34a2a34 -[NSConcreteMutableData appendBytes:length:] + 340
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1b30fcfac writeBytes + 164
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1b30fa01c bufferWrite + 320
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1b30fd144 _appendString + 264
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1b30fa1b8 _appendObject + 348
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1b30f99fc __CFBinaryPlistWriteOrPresize + 528
12 Foundation                     0x1b34a27d0 -[NSKeyedArchiver finishEncoding] + 528
13 Foundation                     0x1b34ed5d8 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 140
14 SwiftyUserDefaults             0x105c9b8c4 $sSo14NSUserDefaultsC010SwiftyUserB0E7archiveyyAC0B3KeyCyxSgG_AGtlF + 292
15 MyApp                          0x104d3a3bc closure #1 in UserManager._cachedActiveUser.didset + 4376716220 (<compiler-generated>:4376716220)
16 MyApp                          0x104d05e10 partial apply for closure #1 in ThreadManager.executeOnMainThread(afterSeconds:withBlock:) + 4376501776 (<compiler-generated>:4376501776)
17 MyApp                          0x104d5fc98 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4376870040 (<compiler-generated>:4376870040)
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9a9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9b524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e8165c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 640
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e81cd0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eecb38 _pthread_wqthread + 212
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef740 start_wqthread + 8

AVAudioSession Notify Thread

AVAudioSession Notify Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fa9198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fa860c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b31533b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1b314e3e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1b314dc34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5  AVFAudio                       0x1bfef65dc GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156
6  AVFAudio                       0x1bff47300 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 204
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eebd98 _pthread_start + 156
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef74c thread_start + 8

Thread #1

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b2fcb940 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eecbc0 _pthread_wqthread + 348
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef740 start_wqthread + 8

Thread #2

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef738 start_wqthread + 190

com.apple.root.background-qos

com.apple.root.background-qos
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1b3206828 mdict_rehashd + 244
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1b30b8f00 -[__NSDictionaryM __setObject:forKey:] + 888
2  Foundation                     0x1b35876d8 addValueToTopContainerE + 128
3  Foundation                     0x1b3587180 _encodeObject + 1756
4  Foundation                     0x1b34a2334 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 360
5  Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
6  MyApp                          0x104d372f8 Album.encode(with:) + 4376703736 (<compiler-generated>:4376703736)
7  MyApp                          0x104d37354 @objc Album.encode(with:) + 4376703828 (<compiler-generated>:4376703828)
8  Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
9  Foundation                     0x1b34a2334 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 360
10 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
11 MyApp                          0x104cec884 Series.encode(with:) + 4376397956 (<compiler-generated>:4376397956)
12 MyApp                          0x104cec93c @objc Series.encode(with:) + 4376398140 (<compiler-generated>:4376398140)
13 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
14 Foundation                     0x1b34a2334 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 360
15 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
16 MyApp                          0x104cfcaf0 User.encode(with:) + 4376464112 (<compiler-generated>:4376464112)
17 MyApp                          0x104cfcc64 @objc User.encode(with:) + 4376464484 (<compiler-generated>:4376464484)
18 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
19 Foundation                     0x1b34a2334 -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 360
20 Foundation                     0x1b34ccea0 -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) encodeWithCoder:] + 876
21 Foundation                     0x1b3586f58 _encodeObject + 1204
22 Foundation                     0x1b34ed5c8 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 124
23 SwiftyUserDefaults             0x105c9b8c4 $sSo14NSUserDefaultsC010SwiftyUserB0E7archiveyyAC0B3KeyCyxSgG_AGtlF + 292
24 MyApp                          0x104d3a7f8 closure #1 in UserManager._cachedSavedUsers.didset + 4376717304 (<compiler-generated>:4376717304)
25 MyApp                          0x104d05e10 partial apply for closure #1 in ThreadManager.executeOnMainThread(afterSeconds:withBlock:) + 4376501776 (<compiler-generated>:4376501776)
26 MyApp                          0x104d5fc98 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4376870040 (<compiler-generated>:4376870040)
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9a9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9b524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
29 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e8165c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 640
30 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e81cd0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112
31 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eecb38 _pthread_wqthread + 212
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef740 start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.root.background-qos

com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b2f12aa8 objc_release + 24
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1c0914680 swift_arrayDestroy + 68
2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1c06d38c8 _DictionaryStorage.deinit + 360
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1c06d394c _DictionaryStorage.__deallocating_deinit + 12
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1c091e320 _swift_release_dealloc + 28
5  SwiftyJSON                     0x105c396d0 $s10SwiftyJSON6unwrap33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LLyypypF + 1400
6  SwiftyJSON                     0x105c394a4 $s10SwiftyJSON6unwrap33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LLyypypF + 844
7  SwiftyJSON                     0x105c395d8 $s10SwiftyJSON6unwrap33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LLyypypF + 1152
8  SwiftyJSON                     0x105c394a4 $s10SwiftyJSON6unwrap33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LLyypypF + 844
9  SwiftyJSON                     0x105c394a4 $s10SwiftyJSON6unwrap33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LLyypypF + 844
10 SwiftyJSON                     0x105c394a4 $s10SwiftyJSON6unwrap33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LLyypypF + 844
11 SwiftyJSON                     0x105c395d8 $s10SwiftyJSON6unwrap33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LLyypypF + 1152
12 SwiftyJSON                     0x105c394a4 $s10SwiftyJSON6unwrap33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LLyypypF + 844
13 SwiftyJSON                     0x105c383e4 $s10SwiftyJSON0B0V6objectypvs + 44
14 SwiftyJSON                     0x105c49ccc $s10SwiftyJSON0B0V10jsonObjectACyp_tc33_4625CC38AABF536BB76490A35D7233C9LlfCTf4nd_n + 164
15 SwiftyJSON                     0x105c49f00 $s10SwiftyJSON0B0VyACypcfCTf4nd_n + 152
16 SwiftyJSON                     0x105c381ac $s10SwiftyJSON0B0VyACypcfC + 28
17 MyApp                          0x104d521e4 specialized NetworkManager.networkRequestResponseHandler(withResponse:completionHandler:retryHandler:) + 51 (NetworkManager.swift:51)
18 MyApp                          0x104d51404 closure #1 in NetworkManager.fetchDeezerTracks(forAlbum:withAccessToken:withCompletionHandler:) + 4376810500
19 MyApp                          0x104d50294 closure #1 in NetworkManager.fetchAppleMusicTracks(forAlbumID:withAccessToken:withCompletionHandler:) + 4376806036
20 Alamofire                      0x105313e64 $s9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0bkF0VyypG_Tg5Tm + 132
21 Alamofire                      0x105319d08 $s9Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0bkF0VyypG_Tg5TATm + 36
22 Alamofire                      0x1052fb3b0 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 28
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9a9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9b524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e8165c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 640
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e81cd0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eecb38 _pthread_wqthread + 212
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef740 start_wqthread + 8

com.google.fira.worker

com.google.fira.worker
0  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1b4df32a8 sqlite3_exec + 26552
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1b4dee810 sqlite3_exec + 7456
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1b4ded6fc sqlite3_exec + 3084
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1b4decc3c sqlite3_exec + 332
4  MyApp                          0x104e1d0cc -[APMSqliteStore beginTransaction] + 4377645260
5  MyApp                          0x104e1cf18 -[APMSqliteStore performTransactionWithError:block:] + 4377644824
6  MyApp                          0x104dd9444 -[APMDatabase performTransaction:] + 4377367620
7  MyApp                          0x104df2a5c -[APMMeasurement writeEventOnWorkerQueue:] + 4377471580
8  MyApp                          0x104df2280 -[APMMeasurement handleEventOnWorkerQueue:] + 4377469568
9  MyApp                          0x104df1500 __27-[APMMeasurement logEvent:]_block_invoke + 4377466112
10 MyApp                          0x104e06f50 __51-[APMScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueueBlockID:block:]_block_invoke + 4377554768
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9a9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e9b524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e78b3c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 564
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e7954c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 396
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b2e8284c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 580
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eecb74 _pthread_wqthread + 272
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b2eef740 start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: from looking at the stacktrace i'd say it looks like the method is actually being called. I'd suggest adding some breakpoints and using the app and see if it hits it

Comment: Hi @Scriptable no unfortunately I cannot reproduce this on my own device. Setting a breakpoint in the fetchDeezerTracks() method never gets hit.

Comment: Can you show the code for `ApplePlayerManager` and `NetworkManager`?

Comment: Sure - I edited my post added the methods and mentioning the class name they reside in + added some additional info. thnx!

Comment: @Scriptable - I also added all the other thread stacktraces. Could it be a thread issue? How could I tell..

Comment: A quick question - have you been able to see this crash in iTunesConnect? Does it give you any different info from Crashlytics, so you could confirm if Crashlytics is showing you the right data?

Answer (score 1):

(Just a guess)

This reeks of threading issues (you can get odd threading cashes if you try and access/manipulate the same object from different threads, and looking at your code you have escaping closures on escaping closures all over the place), looking through your crash log maybe it has something to do with the `UserManager` seeing: this `UserManager._cachedSavedUsers.didset` twice and `UserManager._cachedActiveUser.didset` too, always followed by some writes.

Even shows up on the thread labeled `com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer` but that could be for any reason, just suspicious given all this other stuff too and that `crashlytics` is your crash reporting tool..

App will definitely crash (intermittently) if there's some encoding / property manipulation happening on this user manager / an app-wide cache and its not being accessed in a thread safe way

Comment: Thnx @gadu, after having watched this wwdc video about crash-fixing https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/414/ that was exactly my guess as well!. I will try to make my UserManager class thread safe. I guess I just was not aware that crashlytics was able to produce bogus crash-reports when there are multi-threading issue somewhere else..